# Link to a latest news item with correct url

Tags: categories

I need to have a page, that displays the latest post in the category 'news' or sub category 'news->nen-news'. And I need to be able to link to from the main navigation (news->news article).

My news posts are normal posts with a category of 'news' ( or sub category of news->nen-news).

I have tried to do a page-news-article.php template and then call in the latest news post which works okay. But then the breadcrumbs are wrong because the url is /news/news-article  instead of /category/news/news-article/ .

I need the correct url so the breadcrumbs are right:- home > news > news-article .

Many thanks.

Comment: If it's a single page then why don't you hard-code the breadcrumb to the correct url into the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a page of post. It is quick and very easy

## **HERE IS HOW**

**STEP 1**

Copy your page.php template and rename it to something like page-pop.php

**STEP 2**

Open up the template and add the following header right at the top to tell wordpress it is a page template

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Page of Posts
 */
get_header(); ?>
```

**Step 3**

You need to modify the loop so that it will display the selected category's posts . We are going to make use of [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to create a custom query in which we will call posts from the specific category

This is how your new loop and query should look like. Here you make use of the `cat` parameter in `WP_query` to retrieve posts from the category ID given. Just change `1` to the category ID you need to get posts from

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1&posts_per_page=10' );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

**STEP 4**

Now save the template, create a new page and assign this template to it. You should now have a page that displays posts from your desired category

Also, see the following

- [A Page of Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#A_Page_of_Posts)

Comment: I managed to find another solution - but the tutorial was relevant and I am sure would work 100% - so you get the tick ;]